# Bind a div to a changing variable

Tags: javascript, svelte

There is a loop, which contains a button, on click that button a function runs,

```
{#each newArray as item (item.id)}
<button class="px-2 py-1" on:click={() => settingFun(item.id)}>(Id: {item.id})<Setting /></button>
{/each}


function settingFun(itemId) {
    toggle = !toggle;
    if (!toggle) {
      settings.classList.remove("hidden");
      settingIcon.classList.add("bg-gray-200", "rounded-lg");
    } else {
      settings.classList.add("hidden");
      settingIcon.classList.remove("bg-gray-200", "rounded-lg");
    }
  }


<div class="hidden" bind:this={settings}>
            <div class="flex justify-between items-center border py-2 shadow-md">
              <div class="flex py-3 px-2">
                <div class="bg-[#D9D9D9] px-3 py-2 rounded-lg font-semibold">
                  <Button label="Not Empty" />
                </div>
                <div class="ml-5 bg-[#D9D9D9] px-3 py-2 rounded-lg font-semibold">
                  <Button label="Is Unique" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex relative menus">
            </div>
          </div>
```

i want to bind this div to item.id or something like connected with item.id [item.id is a unique id generated each time on when loop runs] and also use item.id in settingFun() instead of settings.
In Conclusion, i want a different behaviour for each item in loop.

i tried to bind item.id in place of setting but didn't work and caused tab crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make some changes in changes in JavaScript by finding the item based on itemId passed as an argument. After that you can toggle visibility of that div. I hope that helps.

```
function settingFun(itemId) {
  const item = newArray.find(item => item.id === itemId);
  item.toggle = !item.toggle;
  if (!item.toggle) {
    item.settings.classList.remove("hidden");
    settingIcon.classList.add("bg-gray-200", "rounded-lg");
  } else {
    item.settings.classList.add("hidden");
    settingIcon.classList.remove("bg-gray-200", "rounded-lg");
  }
}
```

and html will be amended as

```
{#each newArray as item (item.id)}
  {#if !item.hidden}
    <button class="px-2 py-1" on:click={() => settingFun(item.id)}>(Id: {item.id})<Setting /></button>
    <div class="hidden" bind:this={item.settings}>
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center border py-2 shadow-md">
        <div class="flex py-3 px-2">
          <div class="bg-[#D9D9D9] px-3 py-2 rounded-lg font-semibold">
            <Button label="Not Empty" />
          </div>
          <div class="ml-5 bg-[#D9D9D9] px-3 py-2 rounded-lg font-semibold">
            <Button label="Is Unique" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex relative menus">
          <!-- Add your menu items here -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {/if}
{/each}
```